# Issue fading out selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to fade out a clicked `ul` element.  Here is the thing, I have multiple `ul` elements that contain the same class name for when selecting.  To handle that I am phasing out a `id` for each specific `ul` to know which element to fade out.  My issue is though, when trying to fade out the `ul` element.  Nothing happens at all, even though it contains the correct `id`.

Here is what I am doing:

```
$(".start-dropdownClose").click(function(event){
       event.stopPropagation();
       $thisOne = $($(this).parent().parent().attr('id'));
       $($thisOne.selector).fadeOut();
});
```

When I alert the `$thisOne.selector` it displays the correct `id` of that selected `ul` element.  I just don't know why it wont fade out though?

Suggestions, thoughts?

Comment: Can you share the full code (ul) on fiddle or jsbin?

Comment: It should be `$('#'+$(this).parent().parent().attr('id'));`

Comment: Why don't you just go `$(this).parent().parent().fadeOut()`

Comment: @ohgodwhy create the awnser You got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use its selector, just use the element object:

```
$(".start-dropdownClose").click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try these two approaches:

```
$(".start-dropdownClose").click(function(event){
       event.stopPropagation();
       $thisOne = $(this).parent().parent();
       $thisOne.fadeOut();
});
```

or

```
$(".start-dropdownClose").click(function(event){
       event.stopPropagation();
       $thisOne = $($(this).parent().parent().attr('id'));
       $("#"+$thisOne).fadeOut();
});
```

The first one $thisOne is the ul you are trying to select and fadeout. So just fading it out should work.

In the second approach, $thisOne is an id string, so to select it correctly with jQuery the correct syntaxis is $("#idString")

Comment: The first option makes a lot more sense

Comment: Personally I would go with the first option since its more easy to read and understand.  The first option is the same answer that @sahbeewah answered 48 seconds before my post.